# regex to match ONLY integers and not any strings not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a utility of `Cart` in my website which is built in ASP.NET. In the cart page like it is generally on every page, I multiply `quantity`*`price` to calculate total of individual items in the cart.

For the `quantity`, I have a `<asp:TextBox .... TextMode="Number"/>` control. And have used a regex in a `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator.../>`.

The following is the ASPX code :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" Text="1" TextMode="Number" Style="width: 45px; text-align: center; margin-left: 10px"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExQty" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQty" ValidationExpression="^[1-9][0-9]*$" ErrorMessage="Invalid Quantity!" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Now using this `regex` it functions properly for the following inputs :

**1)** doesn't allow '0' as input

**2)** doesnt' allow negative numbers

But it **allows** the following :

**1)** the input  : '1pppp' , i.e. a digit following by any number/s of character

**2)** the input : 'p' , i.e. only string is also allowed.

I do not know why is this happening.

**NOTE :** I have used a repeater control, inside which there is a text box used for quantity.

**UPDATE:** 
This is the code to calculate the `total` amount :

```
int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < rptr.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("txtQty");
            HiddenField hdnProductId = (HiddenField)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("hdnVendorItemID");

            VendorItemLogic vendorItemLogic = new VendorItemLogic();
            VendorItem vendorItem = vendorItemLogic.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(hdnProductId.Value));
            int price = Convert.ToInt32(vendorItem.Price);

            total += Convert.ToInt32(txtBox.Text) * price;

            lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}",(object)total);
            plcHldrTotal.Visible = true;

        }
```

[image: This is what happens before I remove the cursor from the text box]

This is what happens , it doesn't give an error message but changes the border color to red, and then again when I move my cursor out of it, it removes the border color.

Comment: The `re` seems correct.It caanot allow `p`.The problem is somewhere else

Comment: @vks : exactly... Then why is it allowing the `p` ..  Please see my updated question, I have added the method to calculate the `total` .. Is there some mistake there  ?

Comment: Does removing ` TextMode="Number"` help?

Comment: Just try this ^[0-9]+$, this will match one or more digits.

Comment: @stribizhev : removing `TextMode="Number"` did help.. ! Thank you :) But if it worked without removing the same, then it would have been much more better!

Comment: @Bayeni : Using that still allowed strings/character precedded my numbers! But please check the screenshot that i have added.. That is raised when i write something like  : `2pppp` .. It doesnt give the `ErrorMessage` but it does set the `border-color` to `red` for an instance .. As soon as i remove the cursor from that text box , It again removes the `border-color` as `red`  i.e. giving user a feeling that his/her input was correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that in ASP.NET 4.5, the `TextMode` attribute can have more than 3 values ("SingleLine", "MultiLine", or "Password"). However, these are not yet supported by all Web browsers.

A quote from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/776764/Introducing-Textmode-in-ASP-NET):

> All these new options will only work with browsers supporting these
>   HTML5 features (for example: Internet Explorer 10, Chrome, and Opera).
>   For all other browsers (earlier versions of Internet Explorer and
>   Firefox), these textboxes will behave as normal textboxes.

So, to make your code comaptible with all browsers, you should revert the "Number" value by either removing the attribute completely, or setting to one of the allowed values.

Comment: I am using `Visual Studio 2013` , and in that i have the following in addition to those u mentioned : `Date`, `DateTime`, `DateTimeLocal`,`Email`,`Phone`,`Number`,`Range`,`Search`,`Url`,`Time` .... Are these not approved of ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: The value you are using is new in ASP.NET 4.5. Perhaps, there are compatibility issues with the browser you are using.

Comment: perhaps you are right .. I will try the same on the latest browsers .. To check if the validation works ! (y) will get back to u on this one!